# Changing button actions

Tags: android, eclipse, button

Hey i want to change my button actions. i have 3 classes. when i click on starttur in start, i want to change the start button in the main class to stop, and also change the intent for the button to the stop class, right now the button doesn't work, i think it is because is doesn't have either an started or stopped statement yet, but how do i make a first cycle flag?

Will this work if the user exits the app and then starts the app again, will the app remember which statement was set last?

This is my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

Button bStart, bStop;
TextView tvDate, tvKm;
Spinner spinner1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    tvKm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvKm);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    if (menu.getStringExtra("start") != null)
    {
         String start = menu.getStringExtra("start");
        if (start.equals("started"))
        {
            bStart.setText("Stop");
            bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent stop = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.STOP");
                    startActivity(stop);
                }
            });

        }
        if (start.equals("stopped"))
        {
             bStart.setText("Start");
             bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent start = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.START");
                    startActivity(start);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

This is my start class:

```
public class Start extends Main implements OnClickListener {

Button bStartTur;
EditText etDate, etKm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    bStartTur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartTur);
    bStartTur.setOnClickListener(this);
    etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
    etKm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etKm);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    etDate.setText(format.format(new Date()));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bStartTur:

        Intent menu = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.MENU");
        menu.putExtra("start", "started");
        startActivity(menu);

        break;
    }

}

}
```

And here is my stop class:

```
public class Stop extends Main implements OnClickListener {

Button bStop;
EditText locations, kilometer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stop);
    bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstopTur);
    bStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    locations = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locations);
    kilometer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Kilometer);




}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.bstopTur:
         Intent menu = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.MENU");
            menu.putExtra("start", "stopped");
            startActivity(menu);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If you tell us your end goal then we may be able to find an easier way. What you are doing sounds like it could get more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: My end goal is that i want the button in the main class to change. The button text should change to start when the trip is stopped and to stop when the trip is started. So i want to change the text of the button and also the Intent the button use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to keep the values even when the program is closed, I would suggest you use `SharedPreferences`. You can set a value to "stop" when you click the `Button` then change it back when another `Button` is pressed or whenever you need to. Then you can check this value in the `onResume()` of the class where you want to change the text of the `Button`.

The [SharedPreferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) has a good explanation of how to create, read, and edit a `SharedPreference` value.

[And here is the full docs for SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answers. Do i change the intent for the button like i did in my code then? Or is it another method I should use?

Comment: If you do it this way then you don't have to do anything with the `Intent`s except start an `Activity`. Then you just check in the `Acitivty`'s `onResume()` to see what the value of the `SharedPreference` is and set your `Button` text accordingly.